# Does PMI (Private Mortgage Insurance) exist for commercial real estate assets?

Tags: insurance

Any idea? PMI is used until borrower retains a large enough equity interest in the asset. Do insurance companies offer the same for commercial assets? Help would be HUGE.

Comment: Commercial real-estate is not personal finance.

Comment: @NathanL - as part of my personal investment portfolio I could consider buying a commercial property - so it actually can be considered part of Personal Finance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_mortgage contains information about typical commercial mortgage scenarios. I still think this question is off-topic considering that individuals are not the primary users of commercial mortgages.

Answer (score -1):

PMI is generally something the banks demand when they feel the proposed mortgage is too risky to be approved otherwise, usually because the loan is for too large a percentage of the property's purchase price.

Your first step should be to find out whether they will consider giving you the loan at all. If not, PMI is irrelevant. If they feel they need PMI they can tell you more about what your options might be and how much you should expect it to cost you.

Or are you asking about the possibility of taking out PMI when not required to... And if so, why do you think that would be a good idea?

Generally, if you need to consider PMI, you should also consider shopping for something cheaper that doesn't require it.

Comment: I am asking if commercial mortgage insurance exists....I'm aware how it works for residential assets but wanted to know if such a thing was available for commercial real estate like an office building, retail center, multi-family, etc...

Comment: Kesh, the question is: "Does PMI exist for commercial real estate?"